# Kile: Live preview (compilation behavior)

Tags: editors, kile, live-preview

I like Kile's "Live Preview mode", except for the "Compilation behavior": In the settings, we have to choose one of two:

- Compile documents after saving
- Compile documents whenever there are changes after X ms

The second option is not good, because it will often lead to compilation errors. But even the first option I don't like so much, because I have a habit of constantly saving my document (Ctrl+S), but I don't want to recompile the preview each time.

I found a solution that works for me: Go to "Settings->Configure shortcuts..." and add a shortcut (I chose "Alt+P") for the action "Recompile preview".

The only thing I wish is that now I could uncheck both options in the "Compilation behavior", but that's not possible! I hope this is changed in a future release of kile. Any thoughts?

Comment: I concur, this makes live preview unusable for me.